# Countability axioms and local compactness in a strange topology

Tags: general-topology, problem-solving

> We consider in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the topology of the sets $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which contains for each $(a,b)\in U$ a set like this
>   $$X=\{ (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2<\varepsilon\} \cap (\{x-y =a-b\}\cup \{x+y =a+b\}),\quad \varepsilon >0$$
>   Study if this space verifies the first-countable axiom and the second-countably. Also, show if this space is locally compact.

I supposed that, for each $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. I don't know how to handle this problem... Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean topology satisfies the given conditions. Can you clarify what are the open sets? Note that $X\subset B((a,b),\epsilon).$ But?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mfl has observed, any set open in the Euclidean topology is open in this cross-topology. But there are many other open sets in this topology. Given a particular X, take any Euclidean open set G which contains $X \setminus \{(a,b)\}$ but such that (a,b) is a limit point of its complement. $G \cup \{(a,b)\}$ is open in the cross-topology but not in the Euclidean.

In particular, $(B((a,b),\epsilon) \setminus \{(x,y) \mid y =b \}) \cup \{(a,b)\}$ is an open nbhd of (a,b). You may notice a similarity with your previous question.

Varying the angle of the line removed will help with investigating first countability.

I'll leave local compactness for now, it's past my bedtime.

ETA
Having slept on it, all becomes clear. (Not usually a tactic recommended for exams.)

Notice that if a sequence converges to (a,b) in the Euclidean topology but doesn't include any points in X, then (a,b) is not a limit point in the cross topology. The sequence is closed and not (countably) compact in that topology. You can disprove first countability and local compactness by constructing such sequences in the right places.

Comment: I don't understand very well how to construct the open set $G$ containing $X\backslash \{(a,b)\}$ such that $(a,b)$ is a limit point of its complement

Comment: @mishu I quoted one example in the answer. More generally, imagine a closed set (in the Euclidean sense) which lies between two branches of the X but only meets the X at (a,b). You can remove that from an open ball about (a,b), leaving (a,b), and still have an open set in the cross topology. For example, take the pairs of lines through (a,b) which lie either side of the branches of X and at a given small angle to them. The subset of the open ball which consists of the points strictly between each pair and (a,b) itself is an open set in the cross topology.